# How to redirect to a specific page based on PHP URL parameter?

Tags: php, html, redirect

I'm trying to make a home page with multiple links - each of those links redirect to a login page if the user isn't logged in, then you continue to the page you were originally trying to access. Also I'm a total PHP newbie so I may be forgetting something trivial.

Here's what each homepage file link looks like:

```html
<p><a href="link.php?story=1">Link 1</a></p>
<p><a href="link.php?story=2">Link 2</a></p>
```

etc. And this is the redirect section on the login file:

```php
$story_id = $_GET['story'];
header("Location: link.php?story=".$story_id);
exit();
```

Whenever I load up the page, though, the story_id variable doesn't show up on the URL and a blank page is displayed. Like `example.com/link.php?story=`

I set $story_id to an actual number, the URL has that number and it works fine. Like this leads me to `example.com/link.php?story=5`

```php
$story_id = 5
header("Location: link.php?story=".$story_id);
```

EDIT: added exit(); after header, still giving me a blank url

Comment: is this not creating a loop?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli it looks like it from the code, but OP says it redirects to login first, so we have to assume the code is after login.

Comment: There isn't enough detail here. How if the user is redirected to login, is that variable getting into the login form? And if it is added to the login form, it would be retrieved using `$_POST`

Comment: @Popnoodles added one right after the header, still giving me an empty url

Comment: @hadescode that was just general advice, it wasn't a solution

Comment: @Popnoodles i was told $_GET is superglobal, so from my understanding I assumed that when the user clicks on the link with x parameter, $_GET just stores that across all files?

Comment: @hadescode when they click on a link `index.php?story=1` then `$_GET['story]` will = 1  in `index.php`. You haven't shown how that variable gets to a login form and then posted.